# Error while installing network simulator

Tags: fedora, software-installation

Hi all I'm getting the following error while installing `ns2.34` in Fedora.

Please help me fix

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:420: ns] Error 1
Ns make failed
```

Comment: can you post more of the error message?

Comment: tools/ranvar.cc:219:70: error: cannot call constructor 'GammaRandomVariable::GammaRandomvariable' directly [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose full error is:

```
2. ERROR
tools/ranvar.cc: In member function ‘virtual double GammaRandomVariable::value()’:
tools/ranvar.cc:219:70: error: cannot call constructor ‘GammaRandomVariable::GammaRandomVariable’ directly [-fpermissive]
tools/ranvar.cc:219:70: error:   for a function-style cast, remove the redundant ‘::GammaRandomVariable’ [-fpermissive]
make: *** [tools/ranvar.o] Error 1
```

Solution to this would be:

In `ns-2.34/tools/ranvar.cc`, line 219

REPLACE

```
-return GammaRandomVariable::GammaRandomVariable(1.0 + alpha_, beta_).value() * pow (u, 1.0 / alpha_);
```

WITH

```
+return GammaRandomVariable(1.0 + alpha_, beta_).value() * pow (u, 1.0 / alpha_);
```